# Encrypted android studio layout files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I opened my android studio this morning to continue my project only for me to see that my layout files is looking encrypted or corrupted.

this is what they look like now

[image]

but my app still runs correctly

Answer (score 2):

Delete C:\Users\user\ .AndroidStudio(version you are using)\system\caches.